# recast bot answering fine in it's builder but in slack it's skipping the only intends which have "notions missing"

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, slack, sap-conversational-ai

My [recast](http://recast.ai/) bot is answering fine in its builder but when it is integrated with Slack it skips the only intends which have `notions missing` and eventually spoiling the whole conversation. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a conversation_token ? If yes, are you using your slack id as a conversation token ? If you are doing so, you need to check the box "this is the end of my conversation" within the bot builder or using methods implemented in the SDK in order to reset the memory or the conversation of the bot when the conversation ends :)

[image: End of conversation]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have integrated it using recast bot connector not its sdk and everything was given there which i have filled out in respective places. "End of Conversation" is also checked in those intends where conversation is supposed to reach the end.

Comment: What conversation_id token are you passing to the RecastAI Client when you are making the call to the conversation API ? 

    // With optional parameters
    
    client.textConverse(YOUR_TEXT, { conversationToken: YOUR_CONVERSATION_TOKEN, language: YOUR_LANGUAGE })
      .then(function(res) => {
        // Do your code
      }).catch(function(err) => {
        // Handle error
      })

https://github.com/RecastAI/SDK-NodeJS/wiki/Class-Client